# Virtual hard drive does not expand on a Hyper-V machine

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as a Hyper-V machine on Windows 10 and started some software that wrote about 190GB to the disk and stopped working with a write error 'no space left on device', but I have 270BG free space on the physical disk and the maximum size of my VHD id 464GB:

[image]

parent:

[image]

[image]

EDIT1:

The size within the guest OS:

```
df -h

Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.9G     0  3.9G   0 % / dev
tmpfs                              798M  636K  798M   1 % / run
/ dev / mapper / ubuntu--vg - ubuntu--lv  196G  186G     0 100 % /
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0 % / dev / shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0 % / run / lock
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0 % / sys / fs / cgroup
/ dev / sda2                          976M   78M  832M   9 % / boot
tmpfs                              798M     0  798M   0 % / run / user / 1000
```

EDIT2:

I booted with Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop live DVD and started `gparted`:

[image]

it shows that the size of `dev/sda3` is 463GB.

But when I reboot with my normal installation of Ubuntu Server 18.04 I have this:

[image]

there is no `/dev/sd3`, and it is not clear what partition can I resize.

And what does it mean that the size of `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is 196GB and used is 186GB, but 0 available?

Comment: What is the size within the guest OS?

Comment: @Ramhound see EDIT1, 0 available on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

Comment: Have you increased the size of the partition within the guest OS?

Comment: @Ramhound, no, what is the command?

Comment: You use a partition manager within the guest OS.

Comment: @Ramhound I booted with Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop live DVD and started `gparted` it shows that the size of `dev/sda3` is 463GB, see EDIT2.

Answer (score 0):

It was LVM, see [A proper Ubuntu 18.04 installation](https://developernote.com/2020/11/a-proper-ubuntu-18-04-installation-for-running-ethereum-node/) for details.

If 'Set up disk as an LVM group' is checked while the installation some strange partition of 200GB size is created.